# web2py - for loop and function to change background color?

Tags: python, web2py

I'm trying to make a applicaton where I need the background-color of some images to change depending on "reports" made with "severity" , Red, Yellow or Green.

The view(index.html):

> Welcome {{=auth.user.first_name}}
>
> {{for reports in reported:}}
>
> type="text/css">.eq_img {background-color:{{=bg_color(reports.severity)} (in style tags)
>
> table with images class= eq_img

The controller(default.py):

> def equipment():
>
> reported = db().select(db.repo.ALL)
>
> return locals()

The model (db.py):

> db.define_table('repo',
>
> > Field('body','text',requires=IS_LENGTH(500,1),label="report"),
> >
> > Field('severity', requires=IS_IN_SET(['Green', 'Yellow', 'Red'])),
> >
> > Field('posted_on','datetime', readable=False, writable=False),
> >
> > Field('posted_by','reference auth_user', writable=False),
>
> def bg_color(severity):
>
> > if severity == "Red":
> >
> > return 'red'
> >
> > elif severity == "Yellow":
> >
> > return 'yellow'
> >
> > else:
> >
> > return 'green'

Now it always return the color of the last report in the list. I need it to find the most severe report, if not red, then yellow, then green. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but if you want to set the background color of the .eq_img class to the value of the highest severity present among all the records returned by your query, you could do something like this:

In model:

```
severities = ['Green', 'Yellow', 'Red']

db.define_table('repo',
    Field('body','text',requires=IS_LENGTH(500,1),label="report"),
    Field('severity', requires=IS_IN_SET(severities)),
    Field('posted_on','datetime', readable=False, writable=False),
    Field('posted_by','reference auth_user', writable=False))
```

In controller:

```
def equipment():
    reported = db().select(db.repo.ALL)
    max_severity = max([severities.index(r.severity) for r in reported])
    severity_color = severities[max_severity].lower()
    return dict(reported=reported, severity_color=severity_color)
```

Above, `max_severity` is an integer (0, 1, or 2) corresponding to the maximum severity level found in the records.

In view:

```
.eq_img {background-color:{{=severity_color}};}
```

Note, the above should not be in a for loop, as in your original code.

Comment: That was exactly what I ment, Thanks. Will try to edit the qustion so it's a bit more clear, for reference. If I may ask a follow up; if I, in the equipment view, have a table with 9 images for 9 equipments so the controller has car_reported, house_reported and so on, would I have to repeat the code for each equipment? E.g. car_max_severity=... and car_severity_color=... and the view would change to #car_img{background-color:...? It works, but I would assume in a not so DRY compliant manner.

Comment: You can probably make that more dry. Maybe make max_severity a dict with keys like "car", "house", etc. For CSS, instead of `#car_img`, maybe use `#car.eq_img`, `#house.eq_img`, etc. Then everything can be done by looping over the category names.

Comment: Thanks. That will be perfect. Last issue, if there are no reports for one equipment the code doesn't run, because there are no arguments for max_severity.

Comment: Was a little quick to give up there, fixed it with: if not car_reported: car_max_severity = 0 else: car_max_severity= max(.....) Thanks a millon for your help.

Comment: Or just `max([severities.index(r.severity) for r in car_reported] or 0)`.